# How do I install mailutils with LinuxBrew on AWS?

Tags: linuxbrew

I'm trying to install mailutils with linuxbrew through AWS. However, I get the following error:

```
Last 15 lines from /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/Logs/mailutils/02.make:
make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/mailutils-20160619-9071-1odhset/mailutils-2.2/lib'
  CC     argp-ba.lo
  CC     argp-eexst.lo
In file included from argp.h:22:0,
                 from argp-eexst.c:25:
./stdio.h:409:1: error: 'gets' undeclared here (not in a function)
 _GL_WARN_ON_USE (gets, "gets is a security hole - use fgets instead");
 ^
make[3]: *** [argp-eexst.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mailutils-20160619-9071-1odhset/mailutils-2.2/lib'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mailutils-20160619-9071-1odhset/mailutils-2.2/lib'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mailutils-20160619-9071-1odhset/mailutils-2.2/lib'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a valid installation of Linuxbrew you should be able to do

`brew install mailutils`